# How to delete a nested embedded sub document using MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

## Scenario

I have 1 Collection: **Discussion**

Discussion Collection contains 2 embedded Documents(one inside another)

**Discussion** contains **reply**, **reply** contains **comment**

**I am using MongoTemplate in my Project (Spring with MongoDB)**

My POJO Details:
**Discussion**

```
@Document(collection = "discussion")
public class Discussion {

private String  discussion_id;
private String title;
private String description;
private Date discussion_time;
private String initiated_by;
private Set<String> topic_tags;
private int replies_count;

// List of Replies
private List<Reply> replies;

}
```

**Reply**

```
public class Reply {

private String reply_id;
private String replied_by;
private String reply_content;
private Date replied_date;
private float rating;

//List of Comments
private List<Comment> comments;

}
```

**Comment**

```
public class Comment {

private String comment_id;
private String commented_by;
private String comment_content;
private Date commented_date;

}
```

### Hint

I can able to delete **reply** from **Discussion** Collection.Code as follows

```
    public void deleteReply(String reply_id, String replied_by, String initiated_by) {

    if (replied_by.equals(initiated_by)) {

    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("initiated_by").is(initiated_by)); 
    query.fields().elemMatch("replies", Criteria.where("reply_id").is(reply_id));

    Update update = new Update();
    update.pull("replies", new BasicDBObject("reply_id", reply_id));

    mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, COLLECTION_NAME);

        logger.info("deleted reply successfully ");

    } else {
    logger.info(" Unauthoriszed to delete ");
    }

}
```

I want to delete a **comment** from **Discussion** Collection. can any one provide the solution.

Comment: do you want to remove every 'comment' of every 'reply' in the 'discussion', but conserving every 'reply' embedded documents?

Comment: **discussion** is having multiple replies(One to many relationship). same **reply** is also having multiple comments(One to many relationship).It is similar to **StackOverflow** Question posting. I want to delete a comment from the **Discussion** Collection.

Comment: @zeugor. yes, I am conserving every `comment` as embedded document in `reply`. can you provide any sample code for deleting/accessing **Comment**.